# how to make perl script into installer exe or msi

Tags: windows, perl, installation, pdk

I am creating the perl script/programming's and converting into `*.EXE` by `Perlapp perl development kit (PDK)` application however I want to know whether the same application can use to make the `*EXE` as an `Installer` or `MSI`. Or else we have any other applications to use the `perl script` to make the same.

I would appreciate if someone guide me on this one.

Comment: Building an installer is orthogonal to building an executable.

Comment: Its promise I couldn't able to understand from the above comment.

Answer (score -3):

> I want to know whether the same application can use to make the *EXE as an Installer or MSI

No. It can't

This is a foolish question

Making an executable out of a Perl source file is mostly a matter of combining a copy of the `perl` executable with the Perl code and all of its dependencies

Creating an installer requires at least a number of *checks* to make sure that the target system can support the installed software, a *design* to choose where on the target system each element of the installation should be placed, and some code to *tidy* the system after the installation is done

It is also necessary to write and install an *uninstaller* program that will safely and securely undo every change that the installer has made

It isn't sensible to expect any utility that creates an executable file of any sort to be able to also take all of this into consideration and to create something that will run correctly on a completely alien system